# What is the name of the little black two faced battle robot seen in the first few minutes of Big Hero 6?

Tags: character-identification, big-hero-6

And will there be an action figure? All the other characters seem to have one.

Comment: Still no (official) action figure, but can I perhaps interest you in [a solid keychain](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0450/4941/3792/products/tokyo-disney-land-baymax-goods-05_grande.jpg?v=1599149552) or a [plush keychain](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0450/4941/3792/products/D5H_1028_grande.jpg?v=1599146822)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Hiro Hamada's tiny two-faced robot was called Megabot. Its modular design made it very flexible and distinctive.

[image: A still of Big Hero 6, showing the fight between Megabot and Little Yama]

- As to whether or why there isn't an action figure, perhaps Disney didn't think Megabot was distinctive enough or interesting enough to create one.
- Generally, toy manufacturing is an expensive business and the ten most popular main characters seem to have gotten an extensive treatment. I imagine if enough requests are made for them, Disney will be only too happy to comply if they can make money producing them in volume.

[image: An overview of the Big Hero 6 action figures]

Comment: Thanks and I think Megabot would make a great action figure/toy or alarm clock as a full scale creation. The other characters would be impossible to create and market full scale. Megabot would be a snap to put into a kid's or a young mind's hands.

Comment: I may have to get that Yokai figure.

Comment: Of course Disney now owns Star Wars, a franchise that believes no character is too minor or insignificant to not have their own action figure...

Comment: @razethestray Star Wars has such a huge fan base that it makes financial sense to do that.